# Notation for product distributed over sum

Tags: summation, notation, products

Given the expression $\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}$, we can expand it to sum of products in the usual way, namely the sum of all possible sequences of elements in which we choose exactly one representative for each $j$. How to denote that as a mathematical expression?

Comment: I don't understand what isn't true. In any case, clearly $\prod\sum$ can be converted into $\sum\prod$ with exponentially many summands, right?

Comment: surely $\prod_i\sum_j a_{ij}$ is far from being same as $\sum_i\prod_j a_{ij}$, but this is not what the question is about. a product of sums can still be written as sum of products, with some manipulation of the indices. for example, take the product of sums $(a+b)(c+d)$. this is same as the sum of products $ac+ad+bc+bd$. it is clearly not same as $ab+cd$ as you tried

Comment: Sorry, I read this as the sum from 1 to infinity and the product from 1 to infinity. My bad.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a particularly useful answer to this question, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Perhaps this?
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} = \!\!
\sum_{\sigma\colon\{1\ldots{n}\}\to\{1\ldots{m}\}}
\prod_{i=1}^na_{i,\sigma(i)}
$$

Comment: apparently looks good, unless i miss something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation: We denote with $[m]=\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ and obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}}
&=\left(a_{11}+\cdots+a_{1m}\right)\left(a_{21}+\cdots+a_{2m}\right)\\
&\qquad\cdots\left(a_{n1}+\cdots+a_{nm}\right)\\
&=\sum_{\left(j_1,\ldots,j_n\right)\in[m]^n }a_{1j_1}a_{2j_2}\cdots a_{nj_n}\tag{1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{\left(j_1,\ldots,j_n\right)\in[m]^n }\prod_{i=1}^na_{ij_i}}\\
\end{align*}

In (1) we observe that multiplication of the $n$ terms each having $m$ summands is the same as summing up all $n$-tuples $\left(j_1,\ldots,j_n\right)$ from the $n$-fold cartesion product $[m]^n$ and multiply out the elements of each $n$-tuple.